# Nunjucks: 'if' with multiple 'and' or 'or' condition

Tags: node.js, templates, npm, template-engine, nunjucks

Today my team mate was struggling on how to add multiple conditions with 'and' or 'or' in an if statement in Nunjucks template. After a lot of search he found the answer but not on Stackoverflow. I am not sure if the answer is already posted somewhere in SO but thought to post it now to narrow down future searches.

Below is the answer:

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Answer:

As we know Nunjucks is inspired by Jinja2 python's template engine, the if statement is similar to it.

```
// And Snippet
{% if (VARIABLE > 10) and (VARIABLE < 20) %}
    // 
{% endif %}

// Or Snippet
{% if (VARIABLE == 10) or (VARIABLE == 20) %}
    //
{% endif %}
```

Thats it !!!

Couldn't find this on Nunjucks documentation either. I believe this answer will be helpful as coders working on Nunjucks tend to search with keyword Nunjucks and not with Jinja.